# TFS Api Create Build from Custom Process Template

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I want to create gated.checkins programmatically.I have a custom build template.I can create build successfully but when I want to open  created build definition from visual studio that time In Process tab selected template comes empty but if I go and selected my custom template that time I can see all my property's and configurations .

```
var newBuildDefinition =
buildServer.CreateBuildDefinition(TeamProject);
newBuildDefinition.Name = GatedName;
newBuildDefinition.Description = TFSConstantEnums.AutomaticGatedCreationDescription;
newBuildDefinition.ContinuousIntegrationType = ContinuousIntegrationType.All;
newBuildDefinition.QueueStatus = DefinitionQueueStatus.Enabled;
newBuildDefinition.TriggerType = triggerType;
// ..........................
newBuildDefinition.BuildController = Controllers(buildServer).FirstOrDefault();

var GatedTemplate = buildServer.QueryProcessTemplates(ConstantEnums.BuildProcessTemplateTeamProject).Where(p
=> p.ServerPath.Contains(ProcessTemplateName)).First();
newBuildDefinition.Process = GatedTemplate; //In here my custom template come and I can set it
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: my question is when I want to open build definitation in tfs which I have created programmatically,the build process template is shown not selected

Comment: Ok, I understand your sentence but I don't understand what your question is. What do you expect to happen which does not happen at the moment?

Comment: Is there any property set may be I missed my code to see process template selected in visual studio like newBuildDefinition.ProcessTemplateName="MyTemplate.xaml"something like that .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create Build Definition from Template with TFS 2015 .NET Client Libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39134708/create-build-definition-from-template-with-tfs-2015-net-client-libraries)

Comment: Cannot reproduce this issue at my side. Did you create your process template with the xaml file first and then use it in the code? Have you check if the "GatedTemplate" has correct value.

Comment: What's the result if you manually create a  build definition in Visual Studio and select your custom  GatedTemplate? This will narrow down if the issue is related to your  custom build template.